# Formato condicional para varios intervalos o una hoja completa

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aplicando el formato condicional a toda la hoja, necesito que se coloree de un color la celda correspondiente en las Columnas C, E, G, etc cuando en la columna A:A sea "Sáb".

Por ejemplo, si el día 6 de enero y 3 de febrero (columna C y E) sea Sábado (Sáb) se pinte de un color.

He usado, en el formato condicional aplicando a intervalo C3:Y39 la formula =HALLAR("Sáb";A:A) pero solo me colorea la columna C.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

Usa `=HALLAR("Sáb";$A:$A)`

## Explicación

- Las referencias del tipo A1 son referencias relativas
- Las referencias del tipo $A$1 son referencias absolutas
- Las referencias mixtas tienen un elemento absoluto mientras que el otro es relativo, ejemplo $A1.

En el caso del la fórmula personalizada en el formato condicional se escribe dicha fórmula tomando como punto de referencia la celda de la esquina superior izquierda del rango seleccionado.

En este caso la celda de referencia sería C1, dado que se ha colocado A:A este se interpreta como dos columnas a la izquierda, sin embargo, se requiere que siempre sea la columna A:A por lo que se debe usar la notación absoluta, en este caso $A:$A.